# Capture 'Cut' event from browser context menu in tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Is there a way to catch the cut event on tinymce?

This code:

```
ed.onChange.add(function (ed, e) {
   alert('x');
});
```

where ed is the tinymce editor.

The alert is shown if I press on Ctrl+X in the text.
But if I go on the context menu of my browser and press 'Cut' there, the alert isn't shown.

How can I capture this event?

Comment: There is a 'contextmenu' event but this is only fired when the contextmenu is opened.  I'm also looking for the 'click' event of this context menu which is possibly out of range of the element that was 'right clicked' inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture 'cut' events using jQuery --

```
$('#id').on('cut', function () {
    window.console.log('cut detected');
  });
```

This also works for 'copy' and 'paste'.